# fputws to stderr crashes app

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012

I'm kind of confused if I'm not doing anything wrong, but following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    fputws(L"this fails.\n", stderr);
    return 0;
}
```

crashes for me with the following exception:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x56BEDABC (msvcr110.dll) in errors.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000000A4.
```

I'm using MSVC2012.

I tried to

- switch debug/release modes (both crashes)
- stderr/stdout (both crashes)
- switch x86/x64 (both crashes)
- add /subsystem:console to linker (crashes)
- compile in MSVC2010 - **it works!**

I've got following version:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2012
Version 11.0.50727.1 RTMREL
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.5.50709
```

Comment: The code seems fine, works on my MacBook.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally managed to google the issue, but it wasn't mentioned on SO before, so the link is following:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/772585/fputws-yields-access-violation

`VS2012update1 fixes the problem. msvcr110d.dll version is 11.00.51106.1.`

Another workaround is to use `fputs("", stderr);` before using the `fwputs`, to initialize the IO streams properly.